# Where to get alerts about compromised npm packages

Tags: npm

Just read about the compromised ua-parser-js npm package thanks to the Javascript weekly newsletter.

That made me wonder where can I find news specifically about npm vulnerabilities and also get alerts about them (via email or something) ?

Edit: I'm referring to packages that contain actual malware that can infect my computer. Not the long lists of possible vulnerabilities that npm audit reports.

I checked the npm site there is no warning about ua-parser-js on the home page nor the ua-parser-js page itself.

Comment: Do you know about the `npm audit` command?

Comment: Yip I run npm audit fix whenever it complains. In the past I actively ran npm audit --audit-level=critical but after doing that a bunch of times and only seeing minor issues that don't really affect a web app I lost interest in the tool.
I'm more interested in being notified about compromised packages that contain malware that can infect my computer.

Comment: That tool is kind of the defacto way to do this, although I don't think it can make a distinction between vulnerability and deliberately compromised (malware), so I'm not sure if there's a straight answer to this.

Comment: Seems like it. I thought npm would have some kind of notification system that we can register for to receive notifications about malware. Estimated 188 000 people downloaded the infected versions. Anyway I found this [link](https://github.com/advisories?query=ecosystem%3Anpm+malware) seems good enough just have to check it every week or so.